# How to solve Authorization failed error on calling Moengage Info API on Postman?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, adonisjs-ace, moengage

**API URL:**
https://sandbox-inform-api-01.moengage.com/v1/send

**Error Response:**
{
"message": "Authorization Failed",
"err_code": "UNAUTHORIZED"
}

**DATA API ID, DATA API KEY, APP ID and API SECRET - values for these keys i am taking from Moengage Admin portal**

**Header:**
Content-Type: application/json
MOE-APPKEY: {{APP ID}}

**Authorization:**
username: {{APP ID}}
password: {{DATA API KEY}}

I have tried to call the Moengage info API from postman with the dummy data as payload but the payload format is same as suggested on the moengage official documentation.

**But every time i am getting the below response.**
{
"message": "Authorization Failed",
"err_code": "UNAUTHORIZED"
}

Comment: `Header:` - can't tell for sure from how you have shown it here, but - these _are_ two separate headers, correct? And you did not stick them into one, somehow.